# Passing pointer to function changes data and crashes program

Tags: c++

I am new to c++, but not to OOP. This crash confuses me so much.

This is a piece of my main. This code works. It prints what I want it to print.

```
int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[]) {
    Weapon* wp = createWeapon();

    cout <<wp->name << " " << wp->maxAttack << " " << wp->minAttack; //<<---Works fine
}
```

But. The following code, only passing it through a function to do the same thing, crashes. And I have no idea why. I have tryed anything I could think of, but upon entering the new function, something changes the data and it crashes.

```
void showWeaponInfo(Weapon* w) {

    cout << "Weapon: " << w->name << "\n"; //Wont work!??!
}

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[]) {
    Weapon* wp = createWeapon();

    showWeaponInfo(wp);
}
```

I have debugged, and that shows that upon entering the new function, the data in "wp" changes. The following links are images of the debugging.

[image]

[image]

Am I doing something wrong? Has someone else encountered this problem? Do you have to think of something special when passing pointers as arguments?

Comment: Check if the pointer returned by `createWeapon()` is not NULL.

Comment: C and C++ are different languages! Do **not** add a C-tag to C++ questions.

Comment: Need to see more code. What does `createWeapon()` do?  What does `Weapon` look like?

Comment: `createWeapon()` might crash if you do not have a 3D printer attached.

Comment: Also please do not post *images* for *code* but post in text.

Comment: Did you _licensed_ (read as NULL-checked) `createWeapon()`?

Comment: Most likely, it works in `main()` by sheer luck. Working as expected is a valid form of UB. You probably have a bug somewhere, either in `createWeapon()`, or somewhere else. I know this doesn't help much, but you should show some more code. At the very least, show `createWeapon()`.

Comment: could it be that you are not returning something allocated with new in createWeapon? malloc maybe since you originally tagged it C also?

Comment: `createWeapon` returns a pointer to a local variable. Its lifetime has ended, and the function call overwrites the location where it was stored, causing it to "change".

Comment: I guess `createWeapon()` returns the pointer of stack-allocated variable, not dynamic-allocated. Isn't it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't show us your `createWeapon()`. But I guess the `createWeapon()` returns the pointer of local variable. Is your function like this?

```
Weapon* createWeapon()
{
    Weapon wp(/*blabla*/);
    // ...
    return &wp;
}
```

If so, you've encountered *undefined behavior*.

On the end of `createWeapon()`, the `wp` variable, local variable of `createWeapon()`, is destroyed. Therefore, the returned pointer points to "destroyed" object. If you try to dereference that pointer, the program falls in undefined behavior, which means *nobody knows* what would be happened.

However, **directly** after calling `createWeapon()`, the `wp` variable might be alive - since the stack frame is not touched yet. That's why your first example *seems to* work. But in your second example, you call `showWeaponInfo()`, and the calling change the stack frame.

Comment: This is indeed the case. Now I just have to figuere out how to code past it.  Much obliged!

Comment: @Majkie I think you want to just return by value - like `Weapon createWeapon() { ... return wp; }`. Unlike other modern OOP languages, we need to care "value or pointer" in c++ world.

Answer (score 2):

In VC++ the debugger sets the values of unassigned variables to 204 per byte or as in your case - **0xCCCCCCCC**

This means that your createWeapon() returns uninitialized pointer.